# OpenGL ARToolkit - Calling a draw function based of KeyEvent

Tags: c, opengl, artoolkit

I have two draw functions - "drawComponents" and "drawSignals" which look as follows:

```
    static void drawComponents(ARdouble trans1[3][4], ARdouble trans2[3][4], int r, int g, int b )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numComponents; i++){

        glPushMatrix(); // Save world coordinate system.
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &(components[i].combCoords[0]));
        glColor4ub(r, g, b, 0);
        glDrawElements(GL_LINES, components[i].nIndeces, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &(components[i].combIndeces[0]));
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glPopMatrix();    // Restore world coordinate system.
    }

}

static void drawSignals(ARdouble trans1[3][4], ARdouble trans2[3][4], int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numSignals; i++)
    {

        glPushMatrix(); // Save world coordinate system.
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, signal[i].combCoords);
        glColor4ub(r, g, b, 0);
        glDrawElements(GL_LINES, signal[i].nIndeces, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &(signal[i].combIndeces[0]));
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

These functions work fine if i just call the directly in the MainLoop, however I want to call them based on user input. So if the "1" key is pressed then the drawComponents will be called, and if the "2" key is pressed the the drawSignals function will be called.

To do this I have the following keyEvent function:

```
static void  keyEvent(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case '1':
        drawComponents(config->trans, config->marker[3].trans, 255, 0, 0);
        break;
    case '2':
        drawSignals(config->trans, config->marker[3].trans, 0, 0, 255);
        break;
    }
}
```

I thought would work fine, however with this function, nothing happens when I press the keys. Anyone have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong

Comment: I think artoolkit gives way to register draw function. What else you can do is have two globals telling status of which key is pressed and in draw function check state of this variables and call appropriate function.

Comment: Another way might be to register new display call back and call glutPostreDisplay .